# Carregar XML completo com simplexml_load_string

Tags: php

Tenho um XML que possui um nó pai `Produtos` e 2500 nós filhos `produto`, todos os nós filhos tem uma chave `id` que se inicia no 1 e vai até 2500. Quando tento carregar o `XML` utilizando a função `simplexml_load_string` apenas 2237 nós filhos são "parseados", existe algum limite para esta função? se sim como posso aumentar? abaixo segua código utilizado;

```
$call = curl_init();

$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL             => $import->xml_path,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 20,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
];

$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
// => $xml é uma classe SimpleXMLElement com um attributo `produto` (array) com 2238 indices.
```

Comment: No final dessa xml carregada, ela fecha o nó Produtos ou fica em aberto ? tente aumentar o limite de memoria ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');

Comment: Já tentei e não mudou nada @AnthraxisBR

Answer (score 0):

A partir da versão 2.7.3 do libxml a função `simplexml_load_string` pode receber apenas no máximo ate 10MB por chamada.

De acordo com:

> Since version 2.7.3 libxml limits the maximum size of a single text
>   node to 10MB. The limit can be removed with a new option,
>   XML_PARSE_HUGE. PHP has no way to specify this option to libxml.

Pode se usar `XML_PARSE_HUGE` para contornar essa limitação, ja que não é possível definir direto ao libxml.

Referencias:

[XML_PARSE_HUGE on function simplexml_load_string()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428055/xml-parse-huge-on-function-simplexml-load-string)

[Bug report do PHP](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49660)